# Compact Entity Relation on Drawio

Tags: database, diagram, erd

I am creating an Entity Relation Diagram for my database.

I would like to know if it's possible to make a dense table, I would like to compact all my rectangle in the table.

On the following picture, you have an example of a table of my diagram. I would like to reduce the margin between all lines to create a dense table.

[image: Screen of a table into drawio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was really simple:

1. Click on a rectangle.
2. Click on right, on the tab **"Arrange"** and change the **Height Size**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make sure you select the whole row before resizing the row. There's currently no resize feature for a selected cell, which in other cases does not seem technically correct.